# @font-face in CSS3 isn't working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I am trying to do @font-face for my site, but unfortunately it isn't working .
I tried:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: BN Shirly; /*Adding a custom font*/
    src: url('Fonts/BN Shirly.ttf');  /*Source of font*/
}
```

And then in the span I want to use the text into:

```
#categories span {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'BN Shirly';
    font-size: 30px; 
}
```

How can I fix this so my custom font will work?

Comment: Shouldn't `BN Shirly` be in quotes in your @ff declaration?

Comment: Also, [Font Squirrel has a generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) that you could use...

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
   font-family: BN-Shirly; /*Adding a custom font*/
   src: url('Fonts/BN-Shirly.ttf');  /*Source of font*/
}


#categories span {
    color: white;
    font-family: BN-Shirly;
    font-size: 30px; 
}
```

I just see a space in the font family, just remove the space and try it. And remove the quotes  in your declaration class.

UPDATE

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BN-Shirly';
    src:    url('Fonts/BN-Shirly.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Now I have :@font-face {
    font-family: 'BN Shirly'; /*Adding a custom font*/
    src: url('Fonts/BN Shirly.ttf') format('truetype');  /*Source of font*/
}

Answer (score 0):

First go to this service and transform your font:
http://www.font2web.com/

then do the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Conv_ae_Sindbad';
    src: url('fonts/ae_Sindbad.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/ae_Sindbad.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/ae_Sindbad.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/ae_Sindbad.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Ofcourse replace your font name.

Comment: this site the my font might be corrupted , but it works in my pc .. Can it be because it is Hebrew font ?

Comment: I don't think so, I used Arabic font and it works fine. However, try another font file.